# OpenCV: cv2.videoCapture successful, but isOpen fails right after

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have found some other threads but they didn't help my problem.
The lines that I'm confused about are:

```
print("videopath",os.path.isfile(video_path),video_path)
self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
print("is open?",self.cap.isOpened())
```

It says my file exists (the first line returns true, and prints the direct path to my `.mp4`), and when I put `cv2.VideoCapture` in a try/catch, it succeeded without an issue. However it says the video is not open and I can't pull any frames from it. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, using OpenCV 3.3 and Python 3.5.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: I clean reinstalled and it worked but thanks, it was an issue with the unofficial whl packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it was because I had the wheel version of OpenCV installed on top of my manual installation. DON'T use `pip install opencv-python` as it is not official and errors like this will occur. This was an incredible guide that made it very easy: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

To be clear though, I had gone through this whole process once, and then tried pip just because, and it broke it, so once you install it manually, don't touch the wheel packages!